# How to creating code highlighted blocks on your website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a small PHP framework and I want to make a website where I explain some basic features.

I want to display blocks of php code. Is there an easy to do this, preferably without JavaScript.

I want to have section kind of like displayed below:

```
// This function takes in a value and return it
public function getname($name){
  return $name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server-side there are a few options already out there:

- The built-in [`highlight_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) and [`highlight_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)
- [Highlight source code in your PHP application](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/highlight-source-code-php)
- [GeSHi - Generic Syntax Highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)
- [CHIP: Code Highlighting in PHP](http://www.ewanmellor.org.uk/chip.html)

There are others, but just letting you know there are libraries available.

Comment: Serverside does look interesting. I use a templating engine and I have to see I can make it work together. It will also remove the necessity of Javascript. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Wow highlight_file works amazing for me. It is just what I wanted. Looks lightweight and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

On my Tumblr blog I use [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify) for syntax highlighting. You can have a look [here](http://techpriester.tumblr.com/post/440930541/multiple-inheritance-in-php-with-the-decorator-pattern).

I'm really pleased with its simplicity and it support a lot of languages out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know who downvoted you without leaving a comment, it was not me.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter